# My flag for deleting my question was declined - Why?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

2 days ago I flagged one of my own questions for removal, but before that I did delete it myself. I did this because even if I delete my own question/answer, I would still be able to view it and of course undelete it.

This is the mod's response on my flag:

> declined - Once you delete a question or answer it's gone. No further
>   mod actions.

But a few days before this, I deleted an answer of mine, and noticed that it was fully deleted by a mod a while later ( I'm unable to view it anymore, even got a +2 rep of it because it had a downvote ).

So, can someone please explain the quote? If I want to fully delete my question, what should I do? (just out of curiosity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, nothing is actually ever deleted and I assume even mods do not have that power, and only SE stuff can actually do that. Deleted questions and deleted answers keep living, they are just hidden from lower rep people, and the relevant rep change is removed.

Comment: Yea I've actually read somewhere that users with reputations above 20K (If I'm not mistaken) can see deleted questions. But what about those answers of mine that even I can't view anymore? How were they fully removed?

Comment: @jackJohnson how quickly after submitting the answer did you remove it? I believe is Its done fast enough it will be deleted but after a certain time stack exchange keeps it. Do you have a link to the question?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Actually it was like 2 month or so. I was reviewing my old answers and found some bad answers that I deleted, and can't access them anymore. It was an old answer, I can't seem to be able to remember what was it about.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't be able to perma-delete a question or answer ( unless there's some grace period which allows you to ). When you remove a question or answer you get the rep back that you may have lost and only the author and certain users can view said post. Do note, as a moderator I cannot even permanently remove my older posts.

If we could it would happen very rarely and for good reason, this would not have fallen under that category and was thus declined.

Comment: Thank you alex, Is that about the 30 days period that a question has negative vote, low view, no answer, etc?